# Running multiple shell commands in makefile

Tags: c, shell, makefile

I would like to run something like:

```
grep TEXT file.txt
```

If TEXT exists in file.txt then add a compilation flag. Here is the pseudocode-

```
if (grep TEXT file.txt == line exists)
     CFLAGS += -DFOO
```

I would like this to happen in Makefile. I have tried $(shell command) but it did not work so I am a bit confused.

Thanks

Comment: You can run multiple shell commands when making a target, you just need to put `; \ ` at the ends of the lines. But it looks like you're trying to use a shell command to set a Makefile macro, is that right? I don't think you can do that, the only way to do conditional macro assignment is with `ifdef`, which is conditional on some other macro being defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please insert a line like the following. So it may work well.

```
CFLAGS += $(shell /bin/grep -q pattern /path/to/file >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "-DFOO" || echo "-UFOO")
```

If the text exists in the file, it evaluates to :

```
CFLAGS += -DFOO
```

else if text does NOT exist in the file, it evaluates to :

```
CFLAGS += -UFOO
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, maybe it helps

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/run/ch13_02.htm#x-100-3-prog-make-command

Comment: Just tried it, gives me a missing separator error. Also tried:
echo "ASDF";
echo "ASDF"
@echo "ASDF"
echo \"asdf\"